# How to run a trace in oracle which can capture reads, writes, cpu and duration of queries

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle10g

In SQL SERVER  jargon, it is the PROFILER.

What is that in ORACLE jargon (Title is the question) ?

Or any third party tool(free) is there that does the job?

Kindly guide me as I am new to ORACLE

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you would use [SQL Trace and TKPROF](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/sqltrace.htm).  There is too much to go into in an answer on SO, but the essense is that you "turn on" SQL Trace at the session level (usually), which results in a trace file being written to the server containing the sort of information you are looking for.  You then use the TKPROF program to convert the trace file into a readable report.

To turn SQL Trace on in a SQL Plus session:

```
SQL> alter session set sql_trace=true;
```

Everything after that is then logged to the trace file until you issue:

```
SQL> alter session set sql_trace=false;
```

You then have to find the generated .trc file on the server and convert it to a report using TKPROF something like this:

```
OS> tkprof xxxx.trc mytrace.txt
```

You cna then view mytrace.txt with a text editor.  The `tkprof` command has many options that are documented in the link above.

You can also turn tracing on and off from within PL/SQL code by calling the DBMS_SESSION.SET_SQL_TRACE procedure.